# Can google dashboard filter by column headings

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm looking to do is create a dashboard where the user can filter by both the data in the column and the column itself. For example, the following data shows the Name of the person and their performance in a particular week.

```
Name      WC 11.02.2013    WC 18.02.13

Person1   10               12
Person2    6                4
Person3   18                1
```

I'm pretty new to Javascript and google spreadsheet but it wasn't too hard to setup a dashboard and filter by column entries:

```
var nameFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
  .setFilterColumnLabel("Name")
  .build();
```

But I am completely stuck on how to filter by column. My aim is for the user (from the dashboard deployed as a web app) to be able to show data by both person name and date range (the charts etc automatically changing). I.E. Person 1 performance in WC 18.02.13 (there are a lot of dates)

Any help is very gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: there is a tag: google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the code, but most likely you are creating a [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table) from your spreadsheet data, and linking that with your dashboard using `.setDataTable()`.

What you need to do is to define a DataView instead, that includes only the subset of columns that you're interested in. Here's how you'd show only "Name" and the first date column:

```
var dataViewDefinition = Charts.newDataViewDefinition().setColumns([0, 1]);

var nameFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
  .setFilterColumnLabel("Name")
  .setDataViewDefinition(dataViewDefinition)
  .build();
```

I don't think you can change `dataViewDefinition` on the fly (haven't tried), but alternatively, you could `add()` and `remove()` column-specific charts based based on a list.